# Free delphi skinning library?

Tags: delphi, free, skinning

Does anybody of you know a good, free delphi skinning library for my software? I can't find any free libraries except for AlphaControls Free.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**TBX** still seems to be pretty popular.

http://code.google.com/p/tbxlib/

I've used it in the past. It's simple to use, it doesn't get in the way, and it's pretty lightweight.

**XPMenu** is even easier to use. All you have to do is drop the TXpMenu component on your form, and your whole application will have a new look.  It replaces the painting of standard controls, and it recognizes many types of controls. If you don't want to use it anymore, you just remove the component (and the unit from the uses list).

Over the years I've changed my opinion on skins though. They usually degrade usability (things don't look and work the way users expect) and even flashy looking skins will look very outdated in a couple of years. I think it's best to let the OS decide how graphic controls should look.

Answer (score 0):

SpTBXLib is an expansion package for TB2K components that adds unicode support and skinning and other features:
http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/sptbxlib/index.htm